# number of combinations with all different k's in python

Tags: python, statistics, combinations, permutation

using python 3.8

list = [12, 9, 3, 8, 4, 35, 5, 6, 13, 15]

I want to find number of combinations. However not sure how to implement `N!/k!(n-k)!` when k are different at each position.

So I have 10 position, in the first position I have 12 different choice, in 2nd position I have 9 choices, and so on..

How can I compute this in python and want to understand the logic behind it therefore resource would be helpful.

EDIT: I must have been confused. Product of each element will give number of combinations. Since at each position it has K that reside in other positions. For example It is like choosing from 12 pants, 9 shirts, 3 glasses, 8 socks, and so on...

Comment: 12 or 9 choices of what exactly, to be precise?

Comment: request you to update question with clear information

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you might want to use numpy's [`prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) function :

```
np.prod(list) # Returns 2122848000, that is to say 12*9*3*8*...*15
```

As if you have x choices in a position, and y in another, then you have a total of x*y possible combinations on [x,y].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the values of `n and k` from the given data. I assume, you're trying to find possible combinations for each element in the list. Here's my suggestion,

```
import math
 
def factorial(n):
    return(math.factorial(n))
li = [12, 9, 3, 8, 4, 35, 5, 6, 13, 15]
for element in li:
   numerator = factorial(N)
   denominator = factorial(k) * factorial(n-k)
   print(numerator / denominator )
```

P.S: Don't name variables as python keywords.